# How to permanently disable private browsing in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, incognito-mode

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and Firefox 91.0. I want to disable permanently the **private browsing** (incognito mode).

Especially, I want to stop the keyboard shortcut from working.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the recipe:

- 1. In terminal, go to:
     `/usr/lib/firefox/distribution`

Obs.: This is the correct directory if you are using Firefox version 91.0 and Ubuntu 20.04. Depending on the Firefox version and/or OS this might be different.

- 2. If there is no `policies.json` file, then create one:

```sh
 $ sudo touch policies.json
```

- 3. The file's content needs to be:

```json
{
  "policies": {
    "DisablePrivateBrowsing": true
  }
}
```

- 4. If you are facing problems with "read-only", invoke your favorite editor using **sudo**, such as:

```sh
$ sudo emacs policies.json 
$ sudo vim policies.json 
$ sudo gedit policies.json
```

- 5. Re-start Firefox and try using `Control-Shift-P`. Hopefully, it won't work.